# Unable to get setOnKeyReleased to work in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I'm making a game in JavaFX and my professor gave us a minimal game engine that includes a KeyManager convenience class with a method for checking if a key is pressed. 
The only problem with this is that this then checks if a key is pressed during each iteration of the game loop. At 60fps, this means that even quickly and lightly typing a key detects it as being pressed several times in a row. This sends objects flying to the sides of the screen way too quickly.

I've been trying to set up a setOnKeyReleased handler for the game, but I can't seem to get it to work. I think my problem is that I'm not adding it to the right node, but I've tried everything in my game. I've tried `game.getScene().setOnKeyReleased etc`, primaryStage.getScene().setOnKeyReleased, and the same for every node I have in the game. I don't have anything clickable in the game, so I don't see how the focus can change or anything.

The game will have objects move based on the key pressed, but I'm just trying to get it to print to the console for testing to figure out where it works:

```
 primaryStage.getScene().setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler <KeyEvent>() {
        public void handle(KeyEvent k) {
            System.out.println(k.getCode().toString());
        }//handle
    });//setOnKeyReleased
```

I've literally hit a brick wall and can't figure it out. I've tried several guides and suggestions online to no avail.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the issue might be in the way the KeyManager detects key presses. From what it sounds like you might want to implement something that detects *changes* in the key state, so it might be something quick like storing the state of the key the previous frame and seeing if it's different this frame, and if it is (and if the key is down), firing the event. I'm not sure if this might cause performance issues though...

One thing you might want to look into is just using the `setOnKeyPressed()` method of `Nodes` in JavaFX, since I don't believe those detect held keys (I very well could be wrong though). Another thing you might want to do is calling `setFocusTraversable(true)` or `requestFocus()` on the `Node` that should react to keystrokes, since that appears to be needed to capture keystrokes.

I hope that helps. My apologies for the incomplete advice; my minimal experience in JavaFX was with MouseEvents, not KeyEvents.

Comment: Yeah, I tried something like your first suggestion, but it would occasionally then not read the input.

Comment: Just tried adding requestFocus() to the background AnchorPane that everything is placed on and then doing setOnKeyReleased() for that. Works perfectly. Thank you so much.